# notifyDatasetChanged() not working on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to show the list of posts fetched in recycler view but recycler view is not showing anything. I am using ButterKnife library to bind views and android asyncHttp library to fetch data.

When I used the same code without using any of these libraries the code works without any problem(using async task)

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mRootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post_list, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, mRootView);

        //Initialize
        init();

        //Set progress view
        setProgress();

        //Get post list
        get();
        return mRootView;
    }

private void init() {
        mContentLoader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mPostRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.mPostRecyclerView);

        final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mLayoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
        mPostRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mPostArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        mPostRecyclerAdapter = new PostRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), mPostArrayList);
        mPostRecyclerView.setAdapter(mPostRecyclerAdapter);

    }

private void get() {
        //Request parameters
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("key", API_KEY);
        params.put("prettyPrint", "false");
        params.put("view", "reader");
        params.put("fetchImages", "true");
        params.put("fields", "items(author/displayName,content,images,labels,replies(selfLink,totalItems),title,titleLink,updated,url),nextPageToken");

        BloggerRESTClient.get("/posts", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onProgress(long bytesWritten, long totalSize) {
                super.onProgress(bytesWritten, totalSize);
                mLoaderProgress.setText((long) 100 * bytesWritten / totalSize + "% Loading Posts");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    //Get and update nextPageToken
                    if (response.has("nextPageToken"))
                        mNextPageToken = response.getString("nextPageToken");

                    //Get posts
                    if (response.has("items")) {
                        JSONArray itemsArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
                        for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject itemsObject = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Posts posts = new Posts(itemsObject);
                            mPostArrayList.add(i, posts);
                        }
                        Log.d("size", "" + mPostArrayList.size());
                        mPostRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        setSlider();
                        mProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mContentLoader.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Posts to Show!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);

                //Show error status on failure
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error: HTTP " + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first add your item to mPostArrayList and then use :

```
mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mPostArrayList.size()-1)
```

this is better than using

```
mAdapter.notifyDataChanged()
```

in performance.

Comment: I did the same, first mPostArrayList.add(i, posts); and then notifyDatasetChanged()? Or am i doing it wrong?

Comment: try `notifyDataChanged()` instead of `notifyDatasetChanged()`
or use `notifyItemInserted()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a logical error : It's going to replace the original post items.

```
JSONArray itemsArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
                        for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject itemsObject = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            Posts posts = new Posts(itemsObject);
                            mPostArrayList.add(i, posts);
                        }
```

Change it to this :

```
 JSONArray itemsArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
for(JSONObject itemsObject : itemsArray ) {
      Posts posts = new Posts(itemsObject);
      mPostArrayList.add(posts);
}
```

Rest of the code seems fine.